# How to Disable onclick text highlight in mobile browser (Chrome)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Boostrap 4 to build a Web. A simple code such as below:

```
<div class="col-12 p-2" id="Maincourse">  
  <h1 class="m-0">Main course</h1> 
</div>
```

I use my Android Chrome Browser(version 80.0.3987.149) click on the text, it will highlighted the text and popup google search.

[image]

How can i disable it? I Don't want to set `user-select: none` because I need to let the user highlight the text when long press.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't disable this as it's coded as the default behavior in Chrome.

Comment: @VVV but why other website won't be highlighted? for example, I try to click on stackoverflow text, it won't hightlight unless I long press.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.disable-select {
  user-select: none; /* standard */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* firefox specific */
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome, Opera and Safari*/
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE, ms-edge */
}
```

Source1: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_user-select.asp
Source2: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

version compatibility

`desktop:`

```
Chrome: 54+
Firefox: 69+
Opera: 41+ (15+ with vendor prefix)
Safari: 3+
MS Edge: 12+
IE: 10+
```

`mobile`

```
Chrome for Android: 54+
Android web-view: 54+
Firefox for Android: 4+
Opera for Android: 14+
Safari on IOS: 3+
```

refer to the sources for more info and version compatibility.

Comment: But this will disable user to selecting the text. 
I want to let the user select the text.

Comment: will `:active` pseudo help help you.

Comment: @Hyperx837 what do you mean regarding the `:active` pseudo element? 
Any way to make this work and allow user to select text at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

By adding `role="dialog"` into the wrapper solved my problem.
But I have no idea why, anyone can explain?

Comment: Per my answer, this link seems to explain why adding a role solves the problem: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/tap-to-search

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been doing the `user-select: none` fix for this for awhile and found it unsatisfactory, so I started searching around for a proper name for the feature in order to see if there was better fix/write-up for it and I came across this Google Developers post from Paul Kinlan (apparently the feature is called "Touch to Search"):

> https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/tap-to-search

which describes the behavior in detail and the various ways in which you can disable or enable the behavior.

Relevant excerpts pertaining to your question:

> Tap triggering is enabled for any plain text that is selectable and non interactive or not focusable. When the page has a click handler that responds to a tap on text, Touch to Search automatically detects the response and ignores it since we know the developer intended to handle the event. Using a touch-and-hold gesture to manually select text also triggers the Touch to Search bar. Users can enable or disable the feature using a preference under Chrome's Privacy settings.

> As the author of a site there are often times when you don't want a tap gesture on certain element to trigger a search. To ensure that Chrome does what you intend, make those elements:
>
> 1. Focusable: add a tabindex=-1 property on the element.
> 2. Interactive: Use any of several standard ways to indicate that an element is interactive:
>
>    - Use accessibility markup to indicate the element has a widget role, or widget attributes. For example, any element with role=button won't trigger. Adding accessibility markup has the added benefit that your page will be more readable by visually impaired users.
>    - Any JavaScript click handler that calls preventDefault(), or manipulates the DOM or CSS will not trigger Touch-to-Search.
> 3. Non-selectable: using -webkit-user-select: none; Non-selectable text will not trigger Touch-to-Search even when using the touch-and-hold gesture.